# jhipster generate angular static front-end pages for production

Tags: jhipster

I created a frontend app by doing  jhipster --skip-server but now I don't know how to generate the angular static pages for production.
The backend was also generated in the same way jhipster --skip-client.
In development mode everything works an I figured how to generated the jar for the back-end.
But I m stuck with the front-end, how to generate a working app to be deploy in production , help plis.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify the issue you have? Have you read this doc? https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/

Comment: I edited the question at: how to generate a working app to be deploy in production

Comment: Unfortunately, your edit is not enough for me. It does not say how you plan to serve the JS bundle of your app and this is why I pointed you to the official doc which explains different options like using nginx or integrating JS bundle into your jar but you did not comment on it, so I have no idea about what you tried and what are your constraints. Also what do you mean by angular static pages?